# Find specific lines in a file with bash

Tags: bash, search, awk, lines

I have the following problem. I have files with thousands of lines (and around 1000 columns) and I only need some specific lines. In the second column of these files there is a indentifier which is unique for every line. For example:

```
0 tg573754 0 3455 B H G J
0 tg238576 0 4568 K L E S
0 tg289476 0 3246 L E S D
```

Let's assume there are thousands of lines and I want to extract those 3 lines out of the file. Till now I used:

```
awk '$2 == "tg573754"'
awk '$2 == "tg238576"'
awk '$2 == "tg289476"'
```

Is there a way to combine multiple searching requests in one row or to tell awk that it should refer to a separate file where all the unique identifier included which I need? Probably the last idea is the most elegant way but I don't know whether it is possible.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Best,
Tobi

Comment: `awk '($2 == "tg573754") || ($2 == "tg238576") || ($2 == "tg289476")'` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex.

```
awk '$2 ~ /^(tg573754|tg238576|tg289476)$/' file
```

OR

```
awk '$2 ~ /^tg(573754|238576|289476)$/' fi;e
```

Comment: That works perfect but what if I want to extract 100 specific lines? I guess this way would not work because of the implementation size limit. Or is there a way to change the limit? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use grep for this. In particular, I'd look at `grep -f` which lets you put strings or regular expressions into a file.

I'll make the assumption that the regex will look something like this:

```
^\S+\stg573754
^\S+\stg238576
^\S+\stg289476
```

so "the beginning of the line, a bunch of non-spaces, followed by a space, followed by your pattern". Adjust to fit your actual data.

Stick that into a file "patterns" and run as `grep -f patterns datafile`.

Depending on your system's grep, it may have the -P option, which gives you Perl regular expressions. I don't think you need this complication but of course you might.